# Delete multiple rows in multiple table using INNER JOIN in mySQL 5 TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, inner-join, sql-delete

I want to run this query, but its not working. There 5 tables to delete.

```
terms hav 1 row
term_taxonomy hav 1 row
term_relationships hav 1 row
post hav 5 rows
postmeta hav 5 rows
```

The structure follows wordpress nav_menu

I want to use that structure in my cms. Creating and retrieving done fine but I don't know why the delete statement not working...

Query returns true, but rows are still there.

Here's the query:

```
$query = "DELETE t, tt, tr, p, m 
FROM terms AS t
INNER JOIN term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
INNER JOIN term_relationships AS tr ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN post AS p ON tr.object_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN postmeta AS m ON m.object_id = p.ID
WHERE t.term_id = 1;";
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN postmeta AS m ON tr.object_id = p.ID` shouldn't this be `INNER JOIN postmeta AS m ON m.object_id = p.ID` ?

Comment: yes it should be m.object_id.

Comment: I have corrected this mistake and ran the query... still faild :(

Comment: If you change the top line from `DELETE ....` to `SELECT * FROM` you can see if you would be deleting anything with the query - which obviously you aren't, but then you can work back from there.

Comment: Did not return anything

Comment: SELECT statement is not working too

Comment: Thanks Bill Kalwin for your helps and efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point your `INNER JOIN` condition is ruling out all the records hence nothing is deleted. Here is how you should go about debugging something like this:

Change the `DELETE` statement to a `SELECT * FROM`, records returned in a `SELECT` are the records that would be deleted if it was a `DELETE` statement.

Start off with the most basic query, and slowly add your `JOIN`s back in

```
SELECT * FROM
FROM terms AS t
WHERE t.term_id = 1;
```

Returns a record? Good. So add back in `INNER JOIN term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id`. Works again? Great, keep going until your query stops returning results (or the result set is clearly incorrect) . Once the results disappear, you know that either the last table you added in doesn't have records to JOIN against, or more likely in this case your `JOIN .. ON` condition is incorrect.

Comment: +1 I was writing a similar answer. Good advice to decompose the problem. Note you can also use `OUTER JOIN` in the `DELETE` for tables that might not have matching rows.

Comment: Thanks for the great idea. I am going to follow the instructions. and let you know. thanks OGHaza

Comment: there wat two mistakes in the query. post table was posts and column in postmeta was post_id instead object_id

Comment: "DELETE t, tt, tr, p, m 
FROM terms AS t
INNER JOIN term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
INNER JOIN term_relationships AS tr ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN posts AS p ON tr.object_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN postmeta AS m ON m.post_id = p.ID
WHERE t.term_id = 1;"

Comment: @user3034390 Managed to fix it then?

Comment: You can accept this answer or you can write an answer of your own and accept that (click the tick to the left of the answer).